# how to create secondary top bar in iOS 10 - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

How to create the top bar as shown in this screenshot below:-

[image]

This seems like an secondary navigation bar at top for me.
Appreciated if anyone could give any suggestion on this issue, thanks!

Comment: you can use third party for this https://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu

Comment: It's not top bar. It's a pager strip. User PageMenu as suggested by @Sahil (Y)

Comment: Also keep in mind that this design is more Android than iOS. Just saying ;)